# Angular.js 401 Unauthorized Status Code

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-status-code-401

I want to get access token for authentication. My post result like

POST https://staj-io-goldenilkay92-1.c9.io/api/v1/oauth/token 401 (Unauthorized)

but when I try to post with postman it works.

**Server Side Headers**

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

**Angular Code**

*Service*

```
function signIn(data) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();


    $http.post('https://staj-io-goldenilkay92-1.c9.io/api/v1/oauth/token', data,
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
    )
        .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function () {
            deferred.reject("Failed to login");
        });

    return deferred.promise;

}
```

*controller*

```
  vm.loginData = {

    'client_id': 'client',
    'client_secret': 'client',
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username': '',
    'password': ''
};


vm.login = function login() {

    loginService.signIn(vm.loginData).then(function (result) {
            vm.signInResult = result;

        },
        function (data) {

        });


}
```

[image: Postman Result]

POST https://staj-io-goldenilkay92-1.c9.io/api/v1/oauth/token 401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is suggestions to solve your problem;

Use [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) module (not required);

**Server Side**

*I assume that your **passport** code working properly.*

```
var cors= require('cors');

//init first.

app.options(cors({origin'*'}));  //Use your origins.
app.use(cors({origin'*'}));      //Use your origins.
```

**Client Side**

Just delete headers options

```
//...

$http.post('https://staj-io-goldenilkay92-1.c9.io/api/v1/oauth/token', data)
    .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }).error(function () {
        deferred.reject("Failed to login");
    });
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

If one POST works and the other doesn't, then your angularjs $http request is making the request with the wrong parameters.

I'd suggest you to get an http analyser (like Fiddler) and compare the actual request done by Postman vs the request done by you angular app.