# 401 (Unauthorized) after successful login Angular-node API even using CORS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express, angular-http

I am working in `Angular,node-express API` web app. I am getting Unauthorized even using `cors`. I am very new to asynchronous world. I show My code snippet below.

### node-login API

```
app.post('/login',(req, res, next)=>{
    var userCredentials={
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    }
    auth.login(userCredentials,(err,result)=> {
        if(err) {
            if(err=="notExist") {
                res.json({
                    success:false,
                    message:"notExist"});
                next()
            }
            else if(result=="success") {
            let payload={
                email: userCredentials.email,
            }
            let token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOpts.secretOrKey);

            res.json({
                success:true,
                message:"success",token});
            // next()
        }

app.get('/dashboard',passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}),tournament.getAllTournaments);
```

### CORS-Config

```
let cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

also in same route file.

### Angular-service

```
login(credentials) {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/login',credentials)
        .subscribe(
            response=> {
                console.log(response)
                if(response['success']) { /*note:OUTPUT*/
                    console.log(response)
                    this.token=response['token'];
                    this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard')
                    .subscribe(
                        response=> {
                            if(response['success']){
                                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);/*401 occurs here*/
                            }
                            else {
                                /*Error handler*/
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                else {
                    /*Error handler*/
                }
            },
            error=> {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

### note:Output

I am Getting response as

```
{
   success:true,
   message:"success",
   token
}
```

at Mentioned response.So I am trying to redirect user to `/dashboard`. For that request I am getting unAuthorized from my API side.

I won't get sos from following questions.
[Angular returning 401 unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563531/angular-returning-401-unauthorized)
[Angular.js 401 Unauthorized Status Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098130/angular-js-401-unauthorized-status-code)
[Angular returning 401 unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563531/angular-returning-401-unauthorized)

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: It looks like you are not adding any header containing the token in your get request. You should pass it in the second parameter of your $get and it might look like: ```this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard', { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`}})```

Comment: Thankyou @Dario .... found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed header in Angular `/dashboard` http call.
so Code look like

```
           if(response['success']) {
              this.token=response['token'];
              let value='JWT '+this.token;
              const header=new HttpHeaders({Authorization:value});
              this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard',{headers:header})
```